# Matlab to Python sparse matrix conversion , overcoming the zero index problem

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have an N x N sparse matrix in Matlab, that has cell values indexed by (r,c) pairs such that r and c are unique id's.

The problem is, that after converting this matrix into Python, all of the indices values are decremented by 1.

For example:

```
Before                     After
(210058,10326) = 1         (210057,10325) = 1
```

Currently, I am doing the following to counter this:

```
mat_contents = sparse.loadmat(filename)
G = mat_contents['G']
I,J = G.nonzero()
I += 1
J += 1
V = G.data
G = sparse.csr_matrix((V,(I,J)))
```

I have also tried using different options in `scipy.sparse.io.loadmat`  {matlab_compatible, mat_dtype}, but neither worked.

I am looking for a solution that will give me the same indices as the Matlab matrix. Solutions that do not require reconstructing the matrix would be ideal, but I am also curious how others have gotten around this problem.

Comment: Since python uses 0 based indexing, why not just make the mental conversion when using python?

Comment: I suppose I could.  I'm pretty new to Python.  I just assumed this problem was so common that there was some built-in functionality in the language I failed to notice.

Comment: My advice is to stay consistent with the python/numpy/scipy environment. If you create any arrays once you've moved over to python, they are all going to use zero-based indexing, and all of the methods and slicing assume the same. It will probably be a pain at first to switch, but you'll get use to it and avoid other problems down the road.

Comment: Care to elaborate more on your real problem. Why not just operate internally 0 based indexing with python and the if needed translate them 1 based for matlab processing (and vice versa). Thanks

Comment: I can do internal 0 based indexing.  I wanted to keep the index the same because I have a file that contains metadata that can be accessed with the user id.  I'll probably just reconstruct the datafiles and not worry about going back and forth between Matlab and Python.  Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that a sparse matrix is the best data structure for this problem? If the indices represent something like a user id, then a dictionary might be a more appropriate data type - but this depends very much on what you are trying to achieve. Admittedly it would be more effort to convert to a different data type. If you really want to keep using a sparse matrix, why not just write a simple wrapper function which subtracts 1 from each index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all for the good advice.

I decided to stick with Python.  I do most of my data transfers between Matlab and Python
using text files now.